# this is replaced by SafeSubscriber

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic3, angular5

We are experiencing an issue with our code using Angular5 and Ionic 3.

In our project, we are using a plugin to interact with the camera to scan business cards. When the scan is completed, we need to show an Ionic Loading to tell the user that his picture is uploading. This feature works well on mobile, but the unit tests for the feature fails.

Here's an example of the code executed when the user scans a business card:

```js
public scanBusinessCard(fab?: FabContainer): void {
    if (fab) fab.close();
    let that: ContactListPage = this;

    this.scanService.scanBusinessCard().pipe(
      concatMap((picture: string) => {
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: this.uploadingText,
        });

        this.loading.present();
        return this.scanService.saveBusinessCard(picture);
      }),
    ).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        that.loading.dismiss();
        this.createModal('ContactEditionPage', {contactId: data.contact}, () => {
          this.loadContacts();
        });
      },
      error: (error) => {
        if (error === 'No Image Selected') {
          that.loading.dismiss();
          return;
        }
        this.errorHandlerService.handleError(error);
      },
    });
  }
```

**In the [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) section, the type of `this` is `SafeSubscriber` so we can't access our object's variables.**

We think that's related to the `mock` we use for the test, here's the `ScanServiceMock` code:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

export class ScanServiceMock {
  // The picture returned by scanBusinessCard
  public picture: string = '';

  public raiseErrorOnScan: boolean = false;
  public raiseErrorOnSave: boolean = false;

  public scanBusinessCardSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  public saveBusinessCardSpy: jasmine.Spy;

  constructor() {
    this.scanBusinessCardSpy = spyOn(this, 'scanBusinessCard').and.callThrough();
    this.saveBusinessCardSpy = spyOn(this, 'saveBusinessCard').and.callThrough();
  }

  public scanBusinessCard(): Observable<string> {
    if (this.raiseErrorOnScan) {
      return ErrorObservable.create('Error');
    }

    return Observable.of(this.picture);
  }

  public saveBusinessCard(): Observable<void> {
    if (this.raiseErrorOnSave) {
      return ErrorObservable.create('Error');
    }

    return Observable.of();
  }
}
```

Are we doing something wrong? We tried `let that = this`, but within the `concatMap` section, `that` is `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly fails? What is the error and the corresponding code?

Comment: The test that uses the mock should indeed be shown here as well. @H.B. I've seen this and it's not much about the failing test; in a few words, we expect `this` in `concatMap` to be a `scanBusinessCard` object, but it's not the case, it's a `SafeSubscriber` object when mocked with above `ScanServiceMock`.

Comment: @GabLeRoux: `this` should only be bound incorrectly, if the code is invoked the wrong way.

Comment: Try replacing `scanBusinessCard` with arrow function